# java - use annotations to cascade save objects

Tags: java, oop

I have a base class, Record, that represents records in a database. I have Customer and Job classes that extend record. I've never used annotations before but what i think i would like to do is create a custom annotation and mark a method in my Customer class that return its Jobs objects so i know to save the Jobs objects to the database when i save the Customer.

Something like this

```
class Record{

    private int id;

    public void save(){

        //look up all methods in the current object that are marked as @alsoSaveList,
        //call those methods, and save them as well. 

        //look up all methods in the current object that are marked as @alsoSaveRecord,
        //call those methods, and save the returned Record.
    }
}


class Customer extends Record{

    @alsoSaveList
    public List<Job> jobs(){
        return list of all of customers jobs objects;
    }
}

class Job extends Record{

    @alsoSaveRecord
    public Customer customer(){
        return its customer object;
    }
}
```

Is this possible? can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: [The Java Peristence API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpz.html) would be ideal in this situation.  Study it well.

Comment: If you want it the way you described, you will need to create custom `RUNTIME` annotations and then to use **reflections** to discover them. You can actually have a single annotation `@alsoSave` that will take a `String` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree, typically if your using an ORM then you could let JPA or Hibernate deal with this.  However if you want a programatic response like your mentioning here's a simple example based :

**Define your Annotation:**  AlsoSaveRecord.class

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface AlsoSaveRecord { 
   // The record class type
   Class<?> value();
}
```

**Code to find methods to invoke:** Code you could add to your class example above

```
public void save() {
  List<Method> toSaveRecords = findMethodsAnnotatedWith(AlsoSaveRecord.class, obj);
  for (Method rec : toSaveRecords) {
    AlsoSaveRecord anno = rec.getAnnotation(AlsoSaveRecord.class);
    Class<?> recordType = anno.value();
    Object objToSave = rec.invoke(obj);
  }
}

List<Method> findMethodsAnnotatedWith(Class<? extends Annotation> annotation, Object instance) 
{
  Method[] methods = instance.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
  List<Method> result = new ArrayList<Method>();
  for (Method m : methods) {
    if (m.isAnnotationPresent(annotation)) {
      result.add(m);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

The above will scan for AlsoSaveRecord annotations in the Object in hand and return any applicable methods. You can then invoke those methods returned which were of a result of being annotated.  The invoke will return the Object which you can cast or do something with.

**Edited as requested** to have the "Record Type" defined within the annotation (ie.  @AlsoSaveRecord(MyRecord.class);

The method above can now grab the recordType which is the defined class when annotated

Comment: this looks exactly like what i need. Can you specify a return type in an annotation for a method? For example, could i do something like @Result(Record.class) to ensure that my method marked with that annotation results in the proper object?

Comment: Yes you can add any type of information you require in the annotation.  For example in the annotation class add a Class<?> value();  Now you will be required when using the annotation to use it like @AlsoSaveRecord(MyRecord.class);  The find method above may want to return a Tuple or simple POJO containing the Method and the annotation result value

Comment: is there any way you could add this to your above code? i'm not sure i understand how i would implement this.

Comment: I'm not sure we're on the same page. I'd like to put this "alsoSaveRecord" annotation above my method and then keep it from compiling unless the method returns an instance of Record. Sort of like how the @Override annotation works. If you put that over a method, it won't compile unless you truly are overriding the super's method.

Comment: There is no way to do this with annotations.  I wish... there have been many times I wanted to enforce a Class to implement a particular interface if the annotation requires it.  Since I didn't add a "default value" in the annotation the user will HAVE to put some type of Class when annotating.  I use annotations a lot and have written many internal frameworks to simplify things and what your asking I've wanted myself but Java doesn't support that.

Comment: ahh ok. Dang. I guess i can get the returnType on the method and check that way. Thanks for the help

Comment: Ya, I would use the return type in your case.  BTW, Override is built into the compiler which is why works.  If you really wanted to enforce the type there is a way but it's a lot of work.  You could do your own annotation processing factory and register it with the JVM.  It could halt compilation based on checks for your special annotations.  I would read up on that if you really want to do that.  It also means you need tight control on how your code is compiled so the processor get's executed

Comment: yeah, that's more work than i want to do. Checking the return type will suffice

Comment: David, I forgot to mention I have a light weight fluent Reflection API which is open source your more than welcome to use.  https://github.com/gondor/reflect

Comment: wow. this looks awesome. I can very much see this coming in handy already. The docs look great. Thanks for this!